# How to dynamically update an excel column that contains a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date column that changes based on user input. The user can input any date range they want. I want to automatically update a column to have the same row length as that date column but unsure how to do that. The column contains a very simple formula. for example, A1 = B1*1000. That is the formula that's in the cell. Would anyone know how to do this?

The formula that creates the list of dates (note, BDH is a Bloomberg Terminal function):
=@BDH(B1,C6:K6,B3,B4,"fill=NaN","sort=d","cols=10;rows=120")

where,

B1 = Name of random index, like... Unemployment numbers

C6:K6 = fields (Release time of unemployment numbers, actual numbers, date release of unemployment numbers)

B3 = START DATE (I chose 01/01/2012) This is user input
B4 = END DATE (todays date)

At the end, where it says cols & rows, that is automatically updated by teh Bloomberg API, i did not input that.

Comment: As there are many ways to fill the date column as you described and the answer to this will depend on how that is done, can you please show the formula and how it is applied to create the list of dates?

Comment: @ScottCraner just updated the post